# Problem in multiplication of 2 dimensional lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Actually i need help to solve a problem related to multiplying 2D lists.
The problem is that I have two lists, `a` and `b`:

```
a = [[-0.104],[-0.047],[-0.046]]
b = [[0.183, 0.366, 0.456], [0.971, 0.156, 0.856]]
```

I want to multiply each element in `a` with the corresponding element in the **first** sub-list of `b`, such that:

`(-0.104 * 0.183) + (-0.047 * 0.366) + (-0.046 * 0.456)`

Then, I come again to multiply each element in `a` with the corresponding element in the **second** sub-list of `b`, such that:

`(-0.104 * 0.971) + (-0.047 * 0.156) + (-0.046 * 0.856)`

The result should be 2 elements.
So, I've implements my own code using Python, but unfortunately the code didn't work correctly.

So, I need some help to fix the error in my code.

The code is below:

```
a= [[-0.104],[-0.047],[-0.046]]

b= [[0.183, 0.366, 0.456], [0.971, 0.156, 0.856]]

sumR=0
res2=[]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b[0])):
        for k in range(j):
            r= (a[i][j]*b[k][j])
            sumR=sumR+r
    res2.append(round(sumR,6))
print(res2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for: [-0.05721, -0.147692]

```
    a= [[-0.104],[-0.047],[-0.046]]
    
    b= [[0.183, 0.366, 0.456], [0.971, 0.156, 0.856]]
    
    sumR=0
    res2=[]
    for i in range(0, len(b)):
        sumR = 0
        for j in range(0, len(a)):
          # every list in a as only 1 element
          r= (a[j][0]*b[i][j])
    
          # print(a[j][0],b[i][j],end = " + ")
          sumR=sumR+r
         #print()
        res2.append(round(sumR,6))
    print(res2)
```

Uncomment the print statements to see how the calculation is going

Comment: Yes this is the result that should be produced.. thanks so much the program is working well now :))

Answer (score 3):

Your question is something common to programmers coming to Python from a different language.

Try using what Python's strength are, instead of writing C/Java/whatever in Python:

```
xss = [[-0.104],[-0.047],[-0.046]]
yss = [[0.183, 0.366, 0.456], [0.971, 0.156, 0.856]]

answers = [sum([xs[0] * y for xs, y in zip(xss, ys)]) for ys in yss]
print(answers)
```

(or, if you don't object to using Python's further strengths, i.e. its many great third party libraries, use something like numpy, like @GilPinsky suggests)

A bit of an explanation of the list comprehension: something like `[ys for ys in yss]` causes Python to loop over `yss`, assigning each value of `yss` to `ys` in turn, collecting the results in a list. You can of course apply an operation to `ys` to make it useful.

`zip(xss, ys)` pairs each element of `xss` with an element from `ys` and returns an iterable. `[xs, y for in zip(xss, ys)]` would get you a list of all the tuples from that combination. And so `sum([xs[0] * y for xs, y in zip(xss, ys)])` gets you the sum of all the products of each pair from `xss` and `ys`. It has `xs[0]` because elements from `xss` are themselves lists and you're only interested in the first element of each.

I've renamed the variables to make it a bit easier to keep track of what's what. `x` is just some value, `xs` is a list of a number of values, `xss` is a list of such lists, etc. - similar for `y` and `ys`.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to not use loops in this case.
Take note that what you are trying to implement is a matrix multiplication by a vector, so you can use numpy to do this efficiently as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-0.104], [-0.047], [-0.046]])
b = np.array([[0.183, 0.366, 0.456], [0.971, 0.156, 0.856]])
res2 = (b @ a).tolist()
```